# pandas auto-renaming same headers

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `Python 3.7` with `pandas`.

I have successfully loaded my csv file and placed headers in a list

`csv_file = pandas.read_csv(file, encoding="ISO-8859-1")`
`headers = [line.upper() for line in csv_file]`

However, when I print the `headers`, same headers are suffixed with *.[number]* such as

```
['ADID', 'FIRST NAME', 'LAST NAME', 'FULL NAME', 'ADID.1', 'ADID.2', 'ROLE 2', 'GROUP', 'DIVISION', 'TEAM', 'COMPANY']
```

`ADID`, `ADID.1` and `ADID.2` should all be `ADID` as per the input file.

Is this how pandas treat same headers? Could this be turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not recommended.

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex` - `(\.\d+)$`:

> **.** matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
>   **\d+** matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>   **+** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   **$** asserts position at the end of a line

---

```
c = ['ADID', 'FIRST NAME', 'LAST NAME', 'FULL NAME', 
     'ADID.1', 'ADID.2', 'ROLE 2', 'GROUP', 'DIVISION', 'TEAM', 'COMPANY']  
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c)

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('(\.\d+)$','')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ADID, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, FULL NAME, 
          ADID, ADID, ROLE 2, GROUP, DIVISION, TEAM, COMPANY]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an option called `mangle_dupe_cols` which is by default True (i.e. make duplicated columns as X, X.1, ... , X.N) But this option is not exactly meant to be set as False.

As pandas is warning in its document, "Passing in False will cause data to be overwritten if there are duplicate names in the columns."

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: tried to configure `mangle_dupe_cols=False` but it gave error `ValueError: Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet`. It still is an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262). I'll just do programmatical checks.

Comment: Is your goal to find if there's any duplicates in the column names?

Comment: i guess you can catch the duplicate with bit of messy lines: `test = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/file', nrows=1, header=None)` then `assert numpy.unique(test) == test.shape[1]` which will raise an assertionerror should there be any duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Does your CSV file have multiple headers called "ADID"?

That's not going to work.  Headers need to be unique.  Otherwise, if you refer to column "ADID", how does it know if you are talking about ADID or ADID.1 or ADID.2?

Comment: that is true; script will be used to report "duplicate" headers. Programmatically, it can be done provided that _header names_ does not follow the _.[number]_ notation