# pandas read_csv() returns duplicate entries with .1 and .2 from CSV contents

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading first row of CSV file in to a list using pandas read_csv() method as below.

```
target_df = pandas.read_csv(file_absoulte_path, nrows=0, engine='python').columns.tolist()
```

And comparing the list returned above with another list (expected_columns) as below.

```
if(colums_expected==target_df):
   logger.info("Column names are CORRECT, as expected!")
      else:
   logger.error("Column names are NOT CORRECT!, not as expected!")
imagine, expected_columns=["NewYork","Sydney","Sydney","Sydney"]
```

Now the target CSV file also have the same columns like "NewYork","Sydney","Sydney","Sydney"

When I read CSV using Pandas read_csv() as said above, it returns the contents of CSV file as "NewYork","Sydney","Sydney.1","Sydney.2"

So, basically read_csv is appending .1, .2 from 2nd duplicate column value and which is making comparison fail. If there are no duplicate columns in CSV all works well. And while displaying CSV contents to log also it is annoying.

From one of the answers from this forum, I come to know that dataframe returns dictionary, which can hold only unique values.

My interest is to use dataframe (or pandas concepts) to read duplicates values as it is.
Could anyone please suggest a solution for my issue.

I am using python 3.8. appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what magic you're expecting.  Pandas has provided a solution by renaming the columns.  If you want your own names, then substitute your own names.  You can't have duplicate column names in pandas -- that's just a fact.  If you did, and you asked for `df['Sydney']`, how would you know which one you were getting?

Comment: @TimRoberts "You can't have duplicate column names in pandas -- that's just a fact" is incorrect. `pandas` does explicitly allow duplicate column names. And `df['Sydney']` would return all columns labeled with `Sydney`. There is no requirements for either `index` or `columns` to be unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas auto-renaming same headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809632/pandas-auto-renaming-same-headers)

Comment: Unfortunately `mangle_dupe_cols=False` is still not supported for `read_csv`. [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262)

Comment: You're just reading and comparing the header only? Since pandas is messing that up... don't use pandas. You could use the regular CSV module and read just the header line.

Comment: @HenryEcker, thank you for adding the link. Yeah unfortunately mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet. It would have solved my issue if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care about anything but the header (no need to read the entire file) and pandas modifies column names, don't use pandas. The CSV module in the standard library should work for you.

```
import csv

expected_columns=["NewYork","Sydney","Sydney","Sydney"]

with open(file_absolute_path, end="") as fileobj:
    header = next(csv.reader(fileobj))

if expected_columns == header:
    logger.info("Column names are CORRECT, as expected!")
else:
    logger.error("Column names are NOT CORRECT!, not as expected!")
```

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, yeah looks like I will have to refrain using pandas as per my current situation and go with the way you have suggested. Thanks a lot mate.